# Why do tax and subtotal equal 0 in Magento when a customer with a coupon code adds a bundle to their cart?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, subtotal, tax

If a customer is logged in and chooses a bundle product and puts it into their shopping cart, everything is okay. All Taxes and Subtotals are included if I look into the invoice.

A special customer has a 5% discount of every product (via a shopping cart rule) and chooses a bundle product and put its into the shopping cart. Again, everything is okay.

[image]

But if the special customer adds a coupon code (about 20€), the tax and the subtotal equals 0 and the price is not correct. It equals something magical.

[image]

Comment: It's only really possible to fix code if you see code. My *guess* is that you have an integer division somewhere in that code.

Comment: What a code do you need? Its found that a bundle product with dynamic price equals the error. with a fixed price not maybe that helps? If you need something pleas tell me! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Change the variable data type from int to float. You are likely using Data Type integers, which can not represent decimal places (e.g .0001). Therefore, your numbers are being rounded down and changing results. Hope this helps, if not, please post your code so we can actually help rather than making assumptions.

Comment: Where is it to change in? Thank you for you help